# Can "the world I find myself in" be understood in two ways?

Tags: meaning

Simple monologue:

> This was not the world I wanted.
>   But it was the one I found myself in.

I understand the second sentence, that the speaker ended living in a world he does not like. However, can this be interpretted also that he also found himself like "he was able to realize himself" in that world? Or is such interpretation nonsense?

---

**UPDATE:** Can you use this sentence in a phylosophical or spiritual way? In the meaning of being at some place in which I "found myself"? - *This is the church I found myself in.* - If not what is the correct way to express that someone found himself at one particular place?

**UPDATE 2:** My issue is the mix of the methaprhorical meaning together with position and stranded preposition (*this is the world/church I xxxxx in*)... to me that makes the sentense confusing and the question is, whether it is a valid construction.

Comment: "I found myself in" does not imply anything good or bad about the literal or figurative location -- it's just stating that the individual recognized his position there.

Comment: 'I found myself in Coventry, one wet and blustery morning and there it was that I met my future wife.' 'Having fallen downstairs I found myself in a predicament, with a broken leg and  no phone within reach'. I would say there are two meanings there. But 'finding oneself' in a philosophical way, does not involve 'in', I would say.

Comment: Updated question title and added a bit clearly stated question.

Comment: Your latest edit makes your question less clear.

Comment: The idiom does not imply "stranded" (though it's often used in such a case).  "I wandered around campus for an hour and suddenly found myself in front of Rodin's statue of 'The Thinker'."  You're not "stranded", just in an unexpected or unusual place.

Comment: The interpretation of most sentences that are inherently ambiguous is usually resolved by surrounding context. It's up to the author to explain her or his meaning. But as it stands, yes your text is ambiguous, although the first meaning is the one I would guess.

Comment: I was really interested if the second interpretation of *that specific sentence* is or is not something a native speaker would even consider. Your comment @user contains that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, **to find yourself** may be used either metaphorically or literally, depending on context:

- to find yourself *somewhere or someplace* (literally)
- to find your *Self* / yourself (metaphorically)

Personally I would phrase it, "your Self", because I find the psychological meaning most relevant, but it is sometimes used poetically ("yourself"). An example would be this song, which uses the phrase both literally and metaphorically, in order to dramatize the subject's spiritual transformation. The contrast between identification with materialism vs. with a more spiritually inclined attitude is nicely expressed in the lyrics:

[***Find Yourself***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxXY2-44bCs) by Brad Paisley (Youtube video)

> When you **find yourself** [literally]
>
> In some far off place
>
> And it causes you
>
> To rethink some things
>
> You start to sense
>
> That slowly you're becoming someone else
>
> And then you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> When you make new friends
>
> In a brand new town
>
> And you start to think
>
> About settling down
>
> The things that would have been lost on you
>
> Are now clear as a bell
>
> And you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> That's when you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> Well you go through life
>
> So sure of where you're heading
>
> And you wind up lost
>
> And it's the best thing that could happen
>
> ‘Cause sometimes when you lose your way
>
> It's really just as well
>
> ‘Cause you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> That's when you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> When you meet the one
>
> You've been waiting for
>
> And she's everything
>
> That you want and more
>
> You look at her
>
> And you finally start
>
> To live for someone else
>
> And then you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> That's when you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> We go though life
>
> So sure of where we're heading
>
> And then we wind up lost
>
> And it's the best thing that could happen
>
> Sometimes when you lose your way
>
> It's really just as well
>
> Because you **find yourself** [metaphorically]
>
> Yeah that's when you **find yourself** [metaphorically]

Songwriters: Brad / Douglas Paisley

*Find Yourself* lyrics © Walt Disney Music Company

Comment: My issue with the original question is the mix of the methaprhorical meaning together with position and stranded preposition (this is the world/church I xxxxx in)... to me that makes the sentense confusing and the question is, whether it is a valid construction.

Comment: With double entendres (double meanings of words or expressions) it's up to you to decide what the author really means (whether correctly or mistakenly). It depends on how well you know the author, and context. Often it is impossible to know for sure, unless you question the author about it. Whether or not you choose to do so, depends on how important you feel it is to gain an accurate understanding of the individual, and your motivation for doing so. Questioning can be seen as rude, unless handled diplomatically. But the best person to ask about the meaning of a double entendre, is the author.

Comment: I don't want to leave my question unanswered so I will accept this as at some level it contains the answer. I was more interested in that specific sentence, rather than in general explanation of the idiom. What I take from your answer and all the other comments -> yes, my sentence can be interpreted in two ways and both are equally valid without any additional context. Thank you.